# Excel VBA: Cycling through cells and inputting values

Tags: vba, loops

I am trying to write a vba macro that essentially does this:

Input value for E97
Input value for E98
...
Input value for E102

Then

Input value for F97
Input value for F98
...
Input value for F102

and this cycles until col I

After I need to do the same thing for cells E-I 105:110, 113:118, 121:126

Comment: What is the value you are going to input? Rgds,

Comment: i am inputting integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pertinent to your rather brief definition: to assign the same value (e.g. 1234) to the range of Excel cells use the following VBA code snippet:

```
Dim example As Range
Set example = Range("E97:E108")
example.Value = "1234"
```

The same applied to any other range (e.g. F97:F108). Rgds,

Comment: Sorry for the brief description.  I need to input a different value at each step. So i need input E97, then input something different at E98...

Comment: The simplest way is just to use the code I've posted for each cell, i.e. Range("E97:E97"), Range("E98:E98") and so on. Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted. Thanks and regards,